# How to execute metricbeat while using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

I am trying to execute metricebeat the same way I execute it from the windows command-line but by using subprocess.Popen in a python script.

```
   subprocess.Popen(["C:\metricbeat\metricbeat.exe"])
```

The process starts and terminates immediately although that I execute other processes with the same implementation and they work and don't terminate.

```
    self.process.poll()
        if self.process.returncode is not None:
            self.Shutdown()
```

this is my termination condition and it's always true that's why it terminates.

Is there a way to  execute metricebeat as a background process ? Or what ideas I could try

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```
os.popen("Powershell.exe", 'C:\metricbeat\metricbeat -e -c C:\metricbeat\metricbeat.yml', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```